# AdSense crawler access fails because the bot adds a slash to the login URL

Tags: web-crawlers, googlebot, google-adsense

I'm trying to get a site verified for AdSense. Since I want to display ads in authenticated pages too, I'm setting up Crawler Access to give a username and password to Google crawler.

In this site, there's a username/password form on the homepage, which submits to `autentica.asp`, which then redirects to `logado.asp`.

[image: AdSense Crawler Access configuration]

However, after I add this login, Google understands that `logado.asp` is a directory instead of a file, so it fails to verify ownership because it's appending a slash after the URL.

[image: Google verification fail]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Just use the DNS txt record method in alternative methods... file uploading is not as reliable because if the file gets moved or inaccessible for a period of time then they can disable the account.

Comment: @SimonHayter this question isn't about Google Search Console verification.   I don't think there is any DNS solution or even a file upload solution for AdSense bot being able to access login protected pages.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller has the alternative methods option... screenshot is of Google Search Console, not Adsense.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the redirect, as this seems to be making it unnecessarily complicated for the Google-bot to login to your site.